# NoSuchMethodError - MtomStreamWriter.getAttachmentMarshaller()

Tags: jakarta-ee, wsdl, jax-ws, java-11, mtom

I am using `wsdl` connection and when I get a response I get an error like below.

[image]

However, I already have such a `class`.

[image]

Below is all the `dependency` I use

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.jws-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream.buffer</groupId>
        <artifactId>streambuffer</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.staxex</groupId>
        <artifactId>stax-ex</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
        <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.gmbal</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmbal-api-only</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.staxex</groupId>
        <artifactId>stax-ex</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I do not understand why I am getting such an error.Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: Yes, you have that class but probably it's a version mismatch. For 3.0.0 version of `com.sun.xml.ws` package, that method is deprecated: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt/3.0.0/com.sun.xml.ws/com/sun/xml/ws/streaming/MtomStreamWriter.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have encountered the same issue with `Jakarta` and after enabling `MTOM`.
I use now `Java 17`.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'jakarta.xml.bind.attachment.AttachmentMarshaller org.jvnet.staxex.util.MtomStreamWriter.getAttachmentMarshaller()'
```

In `stax-ex-1.8.jar`, the return type of this method is `javax.xml.bind.attachment.AttachmentMarshaller`, not the expected `jakarta.xml.bind.attachment.AttachmentMarshaller` displayed in the error message.

Here are the problematic dependencies in my `pom.xml`:

```xml
...
<dependency> <!-- Not good -->
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency> <!-- Not good -->
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
...
```

Here are the new good dependencies:

```xml
...
<!-- JAXB API v3.0.1 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- JAXB v3.0.2 reference implementation -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
...
```

`stax-ex-1.8.jar` is now replaced by `stax-ex-2.0.1.jar`.
And then, my client web-service `Jakarta JAX-WS` works fine with `MTOM` enabled.